# Can't send cookies to Apollo Server with express-seesion

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server, express-session

Im trying to send cookies to Apollo Server using express. I even tried multiple alternatives of dependency versions and played around with CORS options and session properties. Still it's driving me crazy what's going wrong. I uploaded my working project on github: https://github.com/sjonnala/graphql-server if someone wants to clone and reproduce the issue. Please help with a working suggestion. This became of show stopper for me to Continue with the youtube tutorial that I'm following.

**index.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "apollo-server-core";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import Express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";
import cors from "cors";
import { redis } from "./redis";

import { MeResolver } from "./modules/user/Me";
import { RegisterResolver } from "./modules/user/Register";
import { LoginResolver } from "./modules/user/Login";

const main = async () => {
  await createConnection();
  const app = Express();
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

  app.set("trust proxy", true);

  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redis }),
      name: "qid",
      secret: "secretkey",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
      },
    })
  );

  app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: [
        // "https://studio.apollographql.com",
        "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      ],
    })
  );

  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [MeResolver, RegisterResolver, LoginResolver],
    validate: false,
  });

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req }: any) => ({ req }),
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground({})],
  });

  await apolloServer.start();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("server started on http://localhost:4000/graphql");
  });
};

main();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "graphql-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "3.6.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "connect-redis": "6.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cowsay": "^1.5.0",
    "express": "4.17",
    "express-session": "1.17.2",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "ioredis": "4.28",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.41"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/connect-redis": "0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "4.17",
    "@types/express-session": "1.17.4",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/ioredis": "4.28.7",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apollo server is applying it's own cors options which will override the ones set by your cors package, so you need to disable it by setting its value to false in the applyMiddlware options:

```
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors:false });
```

This way cors will only be handled by your cors package. I also noticed that you're commenting out the "https://studio.apollographql.com" origin, it needs to be present for this to work.

Or you can get rid of your cors middleware all together and let it be handled by apollo:

```
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors:{
  credentials: true,
  origin: [
     "https://studio.apollographql.com",
    "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  ],
} });
```

Finally, and this is very important you need to configure your apollo studio to send x-forwarded-proto header with 'https' value [image]